# libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, jdk, r

Trying to install the rJava package on R, on my 14.10 ubuntu, using this code

```
if (!require(rJava)) install.packages('rJava')
```

got few errors related to java including jni problems, after reinstalling the jdk, and tried to run the same code again, got that error

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpfFjrp0/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘rJava’
```

looked for solutions, to find just about everyone suggesting (for x64) to execute those commands

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

but that didn't work, is there anything else I can do? I will provide any needed details, and searching for libjvm.so on the entire machine resulted in this

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.25/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_75/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
```

Comment: Had same problem. Executing 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server' solved it for me

Answer (score 12):

Executing the following should solve your problem:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
$ sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Comment: It worked to me. Thx

Comment: The exact path depends on the java version that is used. For me it was `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/`.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need this `R CMD javareconf -e`

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13446026/2803344

Comment: That's what I was missing, thanks! Any way to make it persistent?

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Find your R location. It will be stored in `rsession-ld-library-path` in `rserver.conf` file. Or just by doing `which R`. The location usually is `/usr/lib64/R/lib` or `/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/lib`
2. Find the `libjvm.so` file which is usually in the `usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server` path depending on which jre you're using. Check `echo $JAVA_HOME`.
3. Create a symlink using `ln -s`
   `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/lib/libjvm.so`
4. Restart R server